# How to fetch the value from database using LIKE Keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a table of 20000 records and there I have column which contains some data like `12%`, `13%` ,`123`, `1234`

I want to select the data which contain the `%` symbol. How can I achieve it with the `LIKE` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '%[%]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the percentage % first

```
WHERE column_name like '%\%%'
```

Comment: I think it depends on the DBMS (it works on PostgreSQL)